# how to calculate time complexity for this recursive method?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

for method

```
static void replace(char biStr[], int index){
        if (index == biStr.length){
            System.out.println(biStr);
            return;
        }
        //print result when reach the end of the array
        if (biStr[index] == '*'){
            for (char ch = '0'; ch <= '1'; ch++) {
                 biStr[index] = ch;
                 replace(biStr, index+1);
                 biStr[index] = '*';
            }
            // replace *
        }
        else
            replace(biStr, index + 1);
            //if the digit is not *, go to next digit
    }
```

where biStri is an array of 0,1,*. for example {1,*,0,0,*,*,1}. and the method gets all the possiblities results for replacing * with 0 or 1. using the same example, it will get 8 different results, because there are 3 *, 2^3 = 8.
Does it mean the time complexity is also 2^3? if not, how to calculate it?
and the space complexity is biStr.length, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst case scenario is 2^(n+1). Best case scenario is n+1. Since it's an inplace replacement so program has space complexity as O(n).